# Preventing addons from installing themselves in Firefox, Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, browser-addons

Is there a way that I can prevent a program from installing an addon to Firefox? If I want a firefox addon, I want to have to manually install it, but they seem to tag along with the installation of other products. What can I do to prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution I have found to this is to install an add-on called [Public Fox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/public-fox/). Essentially, I can password-protect adding add-ons, which should prevent them from being added on without my knowledge.

Comment: Tested on Firefox 29 on Ubuntu and it prevents installing addons from the official site. Will test later with `.xpi` files.

Answer (score 0):

If an app is messing with your Firefox program without informing you and/or giving you a
chance to accept/decline, then it is malware that should be purged from your computer
immediately. If you have an untrusted app that you nevertheless want to install, do it
locally within a limited user account, so that it cannot affect files outside that limited
user's profile. Sometimes programs install Firefox plugins, which are a type of addon that
are not really installed in Firefox, being located within the program's installation folder.
Firefox is informed of their existence by an entry being made in the registry key 
HKLM\Software\MozillaPlugins. Those plugins can always be disabled in Firefox and quite
frequently in the program that installed them. If the registry key is deleted, Firefox will
not know it is there, unless the program insists on recreating it.